# Jena RDF Statement Table (Triple Store ) into property tables

Tags: rdf, jena, triplestore

I would like to know if it is possible to  convert a single Triples table that contains all RDF triples into the property tables and the vertically partitioned tables using jena frmaework.

I have RDF file which has all the triples in one table [image]

I want to to know how to convert this one table into property tables which can be described in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.168.3900&rep=rep1&type=pdf

using jena or using any other frameworks

Comment: I'm not an expert, but: yes, that's probably possible one way or another. Can you share a little bit more about what you have in mind/why you need this, what you've got sofar and/or where you're stuck? Try and narrow down your question to a specific problem that can have a concrete answer. See [ask] for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks Jeen for your kind reply, 
I have edited it, How Do you think I can convert or save the RDF triple store into property tables or its vertically partitioned form?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's very unclear what you're after here. You say you "have an RDF file which has all the triples in one table", but RDF files don't have tables. A table can exist in a relational database (or a spreadsheet), not in an RDF file. And why do you want to convert to property tables? And what form should those tables take? Are we talking about some relational database? What do you then intend to do with it?

Comment: Yes, Jeen I want to convert the RDF graph whether it is in its n3 or RDF/Xml or any other serializations to the Relational RDF formats (One Single RDF table) or its property tables described in above paper's link and the vertically partition

Comment: Property Tables have not been in the Jena releases for quite sometime (note the paper itself is 10 years old; it is not clear what it is referring to may be  http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2006/HPL-2006-140.html. The pape mentions Jena1 whcih is very old. You would be better parsing the data to N-Triples and writing your own storage. It is not a very efficient way to handle RDF. TripleStores don't do it that way.

Comment: what's the problem with creating the tables then and fill in the data? I mean, it's trivial, load the data via Jena, create the necessary tables, fill the tables with the data. This is so simple that I don't know where exactly you're stuck? It's just some lines of code in Java. Jena has documentation to load and process the RDF data, using SQL in Java is also documented anywhere on the web. Where exactly is the problem here?